# org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stopServer(Catalina.java:395)

Tags: java, apache

While trying to start the servlet engine, getting the below error:

1. 8080 port is free
2. This error is noticed during starting of the service.
3. IPv6 is enabled in the server.

Error:

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /app/iw-home/servletd
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /app/iw-home/servletd
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /app/iw-home/servletd/temp
Using JAVA_HOME:       /app/iw-home/tools/java
Using CLASSPATH: :/app/iw-home/tools/java/lib/tools.jar:/app/iw-home/servletd/bin/bootstrap.jar:/app/iw-home/servletd/bin/commons-logging-api.jar
Dec 6, 2013 1:19:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina stopServer
SEVERE: Catalina.stop:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:519)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:469)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:366)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:179)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stopServer(Catalina.java:395)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.stopServer(Bootstrap.java:344)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:435)
```

Comment: Are you sure running tomcat startup? you can check in Service properties UI? why does it call stopServer?

Comment: Also check the server.xml for the startup/shutdown ports

Comment: Already checked startup/shutdown ports in server.xml, they are not used by any other applications.

Comment: How do you start the server? try running startup.bat from commandline - Hope you are not doing restart

Comment: This is a solaris machine: when i start it with :

bash#./startup.sh
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /app/iw-home/servletd
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /app/iw-home/servletd
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /app/iw-home/servletd/temp
Using JRE_HOME:       /app/iw-home/tools/java
bash#

Comment: Can you paste your `server.xml`?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to stop or restart the server when it is not running. Instead you need to start it.

Comment: This error is displayed while starting of tomcat itself. Though error looks like we are stopping it before starting...

Comment: Yes, you need to ask yourselves why you are doing that. Probably the answer is to clean up any old versions of Tomcat that are still running.

Comment: There are no other tomcat versions installed nor any tomcat service running already...

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is not running another (defunct) tomcat by doing "ps xa | grep catalina".

Comment: please give me the last line of startup.sh and tell me if you get the same issue when doing "./catalina.sh start" on shell

Comment: Here you go:

exec "$PRGDIR"/"$EXECUTABLE" start "$@"

Comment: sorry. did late edit of my last comment. Could you try "catalina.sh start" ? and how did you check that the ports are currently "not used" ? netstat?

Comment: Same result:

bash#./startup.sh start
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /app/iw-home/servletd
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /app/iw-home/servletd
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /app/iw-home/servletd/temp
Using JRE_HOME:       /app/iw-home/tools/java
bash#

Comment: sorry. running out of ideas.... if you do "catalina.sh stop" ... will there be the same stacktrace?